# Методы Get и Set и модификатор private

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я понимаю, что бессмысленно создавать переменную с модификатором private и при этом оставлять пустое тело метода Set(). Мы как бы защищаем ее от изменений но при этом остается возможность изменить ее при помощи метода Set()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В яве стандарт делать переменные с модификатор private и получать  или изменять их значения через геттеры и сеттеры.  Связано это для повторного использования кода. Например,  если ваш класс используется в нескольких модулях приложения, а в какой то момент времени необходимо изменить логику получение переменной, допустим раньше просто отдавали значение не думая,  а теперь нужно получать значение из БД то лучше эту логику прописать один раз в геттере,  то же и относится к сеттеру.

Если вам нужно сделать переменную, которая будет доступна только внутри класса, тогда геттер и сеттер к ней не создается.

Comment: Алилуя, я понял.