# Почему в ООП рекомендуют для получение значние свойства класса использовать метод, а не напрямую?

Tags: php, ооп, php7.4

Почему в PHP рекомендуют использовать метод вместо того, чтобы напрямую обратится к свойству. Первое что подумал из-за гибкости. Но в том же классе можно использовать для гибкости магический метод `__get()`. Также интересует на сколько это плохая практика, когда метод класса (в конструкторе) генерирует свойства (вместо того, чтобы изначально прописать).

Версия PHP 7.4

Comment: Не во всех языках есть магические методы (например в Java нету, а он тоже ООП), а совет этот просто стандартный и типовой для большинства существующих языков

Comment: @andreymal,  в PhpStorm перешел на версию 7.4 и начал подчеркивать. Также заметил, что еще парочку компонентов было переписано так, чтобы использовали исключительно методы. Например Woocomerce

Comment: инкапсуляция, помогает предотвратить изменение полей объекта, без ведома самого объекта, представьте разницу, между такими ситуациями - Вы пришли в магазин, взяли товар, и у вас наружу торчит кошелек и продавец сам из него берет сколько захочет, причем когда Вы отвернулись, и не знаете об этом, или Вы сами достаете деньги из кошелька. используя метод, Вы можете удостоверится в корректности операции, с точки зрения изменяемого объекта. например проверить что при добавлении денег на счет, в метод добавления не передано отрицательное число, что по факту привело бы к вычитанию.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ через магические методы тоже можно предотвратить чтение/изменение, так что ваш комментарий некорректен в отношении PHP

Comment: @andreymal можно, я тут хотел написать про мотивацию..

Comment: по поводу изменения полей класса через методы я вот тут отвечал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079877/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-get-%d0%b8-set-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-private/1079884#1079884

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну я думаю, что раз автор упомянул магические методы, то мотивацию он и так понимает